# Samsung SMG900S applications

Tags: device-administrator

- how to uninstall android device manager to samsung SM G900S.
- how to remove applications under administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the phone is rooted, you cant typically remove apps that are labeled system apps. You can try disable them, preventing them from running. And some apps that are labeled as system apps cant even be disabled.

But anyways to check and see if you can remove them. Settings > App Manager, then scroll til you find Android Device Manager. Press on it. See if it will let you uninstall it or disable it. If you cant uninstall/disable it. You will have to root the device to remove it.

If you are rooted, You might still need a 3rd party app to remove the app. Such as Titanium Backup, which can be found in the play store. Then that will allow you to freeze/disable the app, back up the app, or fully uninstall it.

**Edit** If you are rooted, When you are wanting to remove apps and if they were system apps. I would suggest freezing or making a back up of the app just in case the phone starts acting up. That way you can reinstall them without having to go hunt for the apk. Cause some apps rely on each other to function right. Especially when dealing with Samsung/Touch Wiz.

Comment: thank you so much, but i don't know how to root my device i tried supersu and towel root but prompt always that there is no su binary installed or not updated. how will i fix that command?

Comment: i want to use my device like before without having a system applications which is not usefull to me and i don't know how this applications appeared on my device. i used to disable and force stop those applications but it keeps on running so stressfull to me. i wanr my device back to normal.

Comment: In the settings for SuperSU you can tell it to install the binary. I haven't ever used towel root, so I cant help you there. How did you install supersu?  Through a custom recovery/odin? Or just downloaded through the play store? Cause normally you have to flash it, via recovery/odin to root the device. Not 100% on what towel root does. But this will help you install supersu if that's what you are wanting to do. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2696537